# Get azure coadministrators of a subscription with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I want to get the administrator and the coadministrators of an Azure Subscription, as in the windowsazure portal if we go to configuration. Anybody knows how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first to install Azure AD powershell module, then you can manage users in your default AD from your subscription.

Here are CmdLets:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/jj151815.aspx